# Block chrome "customize chrome to give your browser a new look" pop-up by adding some registry value

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

How to block chrome pop-up saying "customize chrome to give your browser a new look"  by adding some registry value.

[image]

I tried multiple google search and read the doc but could not fin. Please help if anyone knows it.

Comment: Try adding `--disable-infobars --no-first-run` command line switch.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm this works for some use cases but not for the one I mentioned, for my case the feasible solution would be some registry value location.

Comment: Try asking in https://crbug.com.